# Specify Row Height in Table Style Gallery

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am creating a new table style in Word 2010. I'd like to specify the row height, but the box is grayed out. Is there a way to add a specifies row height to a table style?

Comment: Same problem here. Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010, version 14.0.7116.5000 (32-bit).